# Access res files from Qt for Android

Tags: android, qt, qml

How can I set for example ToolButton's icon to be "ic_not_interested_black_48dp.png"
I have android/res directory in my Qt project, there are some directories for different screen sizes, drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi etc.

What is the best approach to set the correct icon for a given screen.
Does Qt/Android resolve this on its own or do I have to create function that returns me correct prefix 'drawable-hdpi/' or 'drawable-ldpi/' based on my screen size?

Answer (score 2):

While the high DPI support has been [substantially improved](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.6/highdpi.html) in Qt 5.6, the support for varying icon density is [not yet there](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49820).

What you might be able to do though, is use [`QFileSelector`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileselector.html#details). Upon startup, check the DPI of the device's display with [`QScreen`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html) (e.g. [`devicePixelRatio`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#devicePixelRatio-prop)), and then map that value to `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, etc. Once you have the correct string, add it to the list of selectors by calling [`setExtraSelectors()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileselector.html#setExtraSelectors). That way, assuming you have a directory structure like the one below, the correct icon file will be chosen:

```
drawable-ldpi/
    ic_not_interested_black.png
drawable-hdpi/
    ic_not_interested_black.png
```

You'll then need to define a `Q_INVOKABLE` function in a `QObject`-derived class and then expose it to QML (e.g. via a context property) that takes a path to an icon file and calls `QFileSelector::select(iconPath)`. When you're done, your usage of it in QML will look something like this:

```
ToolButton {
    iconSource: iconSelector.select("ic_not_interested_black.png")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to create different size and resolution icons drawable-hdpi means high density drawable-ldpi means its low density

There are A set of six generalized densities:

- ldpi (low) ~120dpi
- mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
- hdpi (high) ~240dpi
- xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
- xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
- xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

[for details](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) it will help you to load your app in high level to low level devices without performance loss.

Comment: This is not the answer to my question.
I expected something more like 
ToolButton { source: "path/to/drawable/" }

Comment: oh ok use this code in xml                                                                                <Button
  android:id="@+id/mybutton"
  android:background="@drawable/whatever_png_name" />